# How to rearrange string after permutation

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using the code below to permute a string according to a specific table.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] IP = { 58, 50, 42, 34, 26, 18, 10, 2, 60, 52, 44, 36, 28, 20, 12, 4,
             62, 54, 46, 38, 30, 22, 14, 6, 64, 56, 48, 40, 32, 24, 16, 8, 
             57, 49, 41, 33, 25, 17,  9, 1, 59, 51, 43, 35, 27, 19, 11, 3, 
             61, 53, 45, 37, 29, 21, 13, 5, 63, 55, 47, 39, 31, 23, 15, 7 };


String text = "00000001 00100011 01000101 01100111 10001001 10101011 11001101 11101111".replace(" ", "");

 text = Permute(text,IP);   
 System.out.println(text);
}

public static String   Permute(String text,int [] table )
{
    String keys = "0" + text;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= table.length; i++)
    {
        sb.append(keys.charAt(table[i-1]));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

**UPDATED**:Any idea to create another method to get the original string back? Something like :

```
public static String   GetoriginalText(String TextafterPermutation,int [] table )
```

Comment: Save its reference in separate variable? ;-)

Comment: Assuming I have lost the original text. how to get it back ?

Comment: Can the permutation table contains twice the same index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a chararray that you populate according to your table mapping

```
public static String RePermute(final String text, final int[] table) {
    final String keys = text;

    char[] chararray = new char[table.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length() && i < table.length; i++) {
        chararray[table[i]-1] = keys.charAt(i);
    }

    return new String(chararray);
}
```

This code is iterating through your text, and writes the char of the current iteration at the chararray place specified in your table.

Note: There are some problems in your code that i left untouched.
For example I really don't get why you allways put "0" in front of your text.
Also you might want to handle situations where the passed text and table differ in length.

**Edit:** I removed the part where you add "0" in front of your passed text and instead changed the loop to start at i=0 instead i=1.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement `text = Permute(text,IP);` you are assigning reference of `String` object returning from `Permute` function, so the original reference which `text` variable was holding is replaced by new reference returned by `Permute` function.

If you want to keep the original reference which `text` was holding, just use any other variable like `String output = Permute(text,IP);`.

You could use a simple program as mentioned below:

```
public static String dePermute(String text, int[] table){

    String keys = text;

    System.out.println(table.length);
    String[] str = new String[table.length];

    for (int i = 1; i <= table.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Coming "+table[i - 1]);
        str[table[i - 1]-1] = ""+keys.charAt(i-1);
        //sb.append(keys.charAt(table[i - 1]));
    }


    return Arrays.toString(str).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace(",", "").replace(" ", "");
}
```

You can use the concept explained in this program. I have just reverse the process which you are doing in `Permute` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your algorithm to use array of chars instead of `StringBuilder`:

```
public static String permute(String text,int [] table )
{
    char[] chars = new char[table.length];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < table.length; i++) {
        chars[i] = text.charAt(table[i]-1);
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

After that reverse algorithm is more obvious. You just need to make reverse assignment:

```
public static  String undo(String text,int [] table ) {
    char[] chars = new char[table.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
    {
        chars[table[i]-1] = text.charAt(i);
    }

    return new String(chars);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming your permutation table doesn't change you can do this:

```
public static String   GetoriginalText(String TextafterPermutation,int [] table ){

   char[] chars=new char[table.length];

   for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++){
     chars[table[i] - 1] = TextafterPermutation.charAt(i);
   }

   return new String(chars);

}
```